# Enforce Timezone in Elastic Search Index

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash

I have net flow data that's `DateTime` is in local timezone (GMT+10). However when elastic search creates the index it assumes that the data is in `UTC`, therefore all my times are skewed. Just wondering if there is a way to say to elastic search that the data is in local and not UTC?

Comment: It's a good practice to store your date/time in UTC and then apply the timezone settings when querying and displaying your data. However, it's definitely possible to store date/time in GMT+10, it just depends on your indexing logic, what does it do?

Comment: If your are parsing your date with the logstash date filter, you can use the timezone configuration option ([date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-timezone)) to set a timezone on the parsed dates.

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I have the similar problem